# Getting com ports in Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, serial-port, port

I ran into the same problem. When I try to get com ports through Python, I get an empty list. I'm trying to get it using this code:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports


class Ports():

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_ports():
        com_ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        print(f'Ports - {com_ports}')

        return [port.device for port in com_ports]


ex_class = Ports().get_all_ports()

print(ex_class)
```

This is what I get with the following console commands:

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.118256] printk: console [tty0] enabled
```

```
$ python -m serial.tools.list_ports
no ports found
```

I use Python version 3.10 and Ubuntu version 20.04.

I need to get all the ports for further implementation in PyQT5

Comment: Few computers have serial ports.  tty0 is not a serial port